# API doesn't respond for AT&T customers' network

Tags: ios, swift, go, alamofire

I have a VPS on Digital Ocean NYC3. When AT&T users make a request for my API from iOS app for registering app which is a POST request, they can't even reach my server. I'm serving my Go app from port 777 but I changed nginx's proxy_pass settings. I even tested with 8001, 8081 port if it has an effect or not but it doesn't.

Funny thing about that problem, before registration, they have to make a GET request for check their email if it's eligible or not, that request has reached my server and get response.

I don't want to change every request to GET request just to make it work.

Does anyone ever faced a problem something like that?

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that connectivity to your server depends on the HTTP method. In any case, you should really serve your API over TLS, which would rule out this possibility completely.

Comment: I'm serving app with ListenAndServeTLS, only responds to https request.

Comment: Are you sure you are not receiving the REQUEST? Check in your ngnix access log (/var/log/nginx/access.log)

Comment: If it's HTTPS all the way (and not just between nginx and Go) then AT&T (or any other party involved) can't possibly know the HTTP method and mess with connections based on that. Again, this is a red herring.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this, as I am having this issue as well?